Consequences of intersection product equal to $0$
We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety, let $D$ be a nef prime divisor and let $C$ be a smooth irreducible curve.
I know that, if $D\cap C=\emptyset$, then $D\cdot C = 0$.
My question(s) is the following:

Does the converse hold? I believe not. I don't have a detailed example on my mind, but I guess the curve may intersect the divisor in two points $p,q$, and the degree of the pullback of the divisor might become $\text{deg}(-p+q)=0$;

If 1. does not hold, suppose in addition that I know that $|D\cap C|=1$, that is they intersect exactly in one point. Then necessarily $D\cdot C \neq 0$, right?


I think the newness hypothesis does not play a role in this situation, but I'll leave it since it is an extra hypothesis I have in my problem.

No, the converse does not hold. The issue occurs if $C$ is contained in $D$. Then obviously $D$ and $C$ are not disjoint, but nevertheless one can have $D\cdot C=0$. The simplest example is to take $X=\mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$ and $D=C$ a fibre of one of the two rulings.
However, if $C$ is not contained in $D$, then they must intersect properly in $k$ points, for some $k \geq 0$, and in this case we have $D \cdot C \geq k$. (In general we do not have equality here, since the multiplicity of intersection may be strictly greater than 1 at some point). In particular the answer to your second question is "yes, that is right".

Great answer +1. Just to add that two irreducible curves which are not equal necessarily intersect in finite number of points. So for irreducible curves $C\cdot D = 0 $ and $C \neq D$ $\implies$  $C \cap D = \emptyset$.

@NickL: yes, that is a good point to clarify. Let me add that.

Dear @LazzaroCampeotti, thank you very much for the answer. I'll gladly accept it, but may I ask one thing, if you have time? Could you please provide an explanation (a reference is more than enough) about the statement that if $C\not\subset D$, then they must intersect properly in $k$ points?

Yes. Maybe the adjective "properly" is unnecessarily confusing here. All I mean is that if $C$ is not contained in $D$, then their intersection set is either empty (i.e. they intersect in $k=0$ points) or is of dimension zero, hence is a finite set of $k \geq 1$ points on $C$. Is that more clear?
